# What if both If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match are present in HTTP headers

Tags: http, http-headers

I've been reading [RFC 2616 - sec14.26](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26) and [RFC 2616 - sec13.3.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.3) for quite a long time, but I'm still not sure if I understand correctly.

The section 14.26 states that

> If any of the **entity tags match the entity tag** of the entity that would have been returned in the response to a similar GET request (without the If-None-Match header) on that resource, or if "*" is given and any current entity exists for that resource, then the server MUST NOT perform the requested method, unless required to do so because the resource's modification date **fails to match that supplied in an If-Modified-Since header** field in the request. Instead, if the request method was GET or HEAD, the server SHOULD respond with a **304 (Not Modified) response**, including the cache- related header fields (particularly ETag) of one of the entities that matched.

,

> If **none of the entity tags match**, then the server MAY perform the requested method as if the If-None-Match header field did not exist, but MUST also ignore any If-Modified-Since header field(s) in the request. That is, if no entity tags match, then the server **MUST NOT return a 304 (Not Modified) response**.

and the section 13.3.3 states that

> An HTTP/1.1 origin server, upon receiving a conditional request that includes both a Last-Modified date (e.g., in an If-Modified-Since or If-Unmodified-Since header field) and one or more entity tags (e.g., in an If-Match, If-None-Match, or If-Range header field) as cache validators, MUST NOT return a response status of 304 (Not Modified) unless doing so is **consistent with all of the conditional header fields** in the request.

I'm quite confused whether a *unconditionally compliant* HTTP server should response to a client request (`GET` / `HEAD`) where

1. the condition `If-Modified-Since` matches, but `If-None-Match` doesn't.
2. or, the condition `If-None-Match` matches, but `If-Modified-Since` doesn't.

According to the section 14.26, 304 Not Modified should be returned in the first case and 200 OK in the second case since `If-Modified-Since` is ignored.

But the section 13.3.3 says that *"it MUST NOT return a response status of 304 (Not Modified) unless doing so is consistent with all of the conditional header fields in the request."*, meaning that 200 OK should be returned in the both cases.

Comment: RFC 2616 is obsolete. Please have a look at http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7232.html instead.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

from RFC 7232

> A recipient must ignore If-Modified-Since if the request contains an If-None-Match header field; the condition in If-None-Match is considered to be a more accurate replacement for the condition in If-Modified-Since, and the two are only combined for the sake of interoperating with older intermediaries that might not implement If-None-Match.